# Declare a base variable for methods in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**The answer is below**

*I'm just starting to get into JQuery but I don't if I'm just slow understanding or stupid.... 
Let's say I wanna make a function where all my li objects... when you do a mouseover it gets the class name of the corresponding li element, and declaring a variable inside of it to keep that name, well my question is... how can I edit it with .css method and make a simple image swap ( image which is find through the class)*

```
$("li")
.mouseover(function() { 
        var $myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    var src = $($myClass).find('img').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
    $("img"+ myClass).attr("src", src);


$($myClass).css("background-color", "#fff");
    })
```

*I don't know why it's not working, i'm guessing it's because my variable only display the name and not the actual name to edit it with jquery, I mean I don't know if it's adding the "." or "#" depending if it's a div or class for the code syntax, but I have no idea how to add that "." to the variable... or maybe it's because of my nested rules with my li objects, I mean to specifically refer to my li objects is:*

> #nav li

*And yeah I know I'm telling solutions but I can't make em work :S
Anyone can help me?*

**I did it haha! (What I was trying to do is change an `<image>` (with generic name) and class properties inside of a specific li object, knowing that li through their class when user triggers mouse over)

I'm just adding the code if anyone find this question helpful**.

```
  $("li")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var $myClass = $(this).attr("class");
        $myClass = "." + $myClass + " a";
        var src = $($myClass).find('img').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
        $myImg =  $myClass + " img";
        $($myImg).attr("src", src);
        $($myClass).css("color", "#fff");
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var $myClass = $(this).attr("class")
        $myClass = "." + $myClass + " a";
        var src = $($myClass).find('img').attr("src").replace("_over", "");
        $myImg =  $myClass + " img";
        $($myImg).attr("src", src);
        $($myClass).css("color", "#E3C922");
    });
```

Comment: If your trying then you're not being stupid, giving up would be being stupid :-)

Comment: I recommend you the CSS solution proposed by @kai-qing because is faster (not for IE8-), cleaner an easier. If you ar going to work with IE, is always faster to manage the hover event with JS than CSS, and I would still recommend a class toggle implementation, giving the  background changing work to the CSS.

Comment: thanks guys! I know I can do this with css, I was trying to do it in another way, adding an <img> and text in that li object but solving it only with jquery, u know like a excercise to practise, but i guess I'll try this another day kinda in a hurry and im wasting time learning lol!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this in css:

```
.yourClass{
    background: url(/path/image.jpg);
}

.yourClass:hover{
    background: url(/path/image_over.jpg);
}
```

unless you have individual images for each li. Then you may want to clarify your needs so I can update this to a more useful answer.

just in case...

```
$("li")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).find('img').attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_over.png";
        $(this).find("img").attr("src", src);
        $(this).css("background-color", "#fff");
    })
```

there's no reason to declare the myCLass var when you're within scope of that object alone. So you add the over state, then change the src of the img found and the li's background color.

Comment: but when you refer to li you're referring to all the li objects that's why I'm adding a function which gets the names of that class and look inside of that specific class, so it dosen't affect all li elements, I got an image and text in that <li> tag, what I'm trying to do is swicth both image and color class on mouse over based on the containing, I know i can do this with css, but if I want both text and image to switch I'll have to use a background image on that object, but I'm just trying to do it with a <img> obj

Comment: what I'm trying to do too is not to repeat same function for each li elemnet

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to have one css class for the "li" element when it is not being hovered over and then another css class for when it is being hovered over with the background image set to whatever you want.

Then, in your jQuery you would use the removeClass() function and the addClass() function. The addClass() function would add the class with your hovered image.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to change the class on mouse over?

```
   $(li).mouseover(function{$(this).addClass("whatever");});
    $(li).mouseout(function{$(this).removeClass("whatever");});
```

you can also use `toggleClass()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **$varname** method for variable declaration **var** keyword